# React Native module not working only on iOS

Tags: react-native

I have recently upgraded my react-native project to 0.60. After upgrading, a native module I have been working with has stopped working on iOS, with the error TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined.

I have been modifying this native module but the only code I had modified after upgrading to RN 0.60 was Android code. My modified module code is at https://github.com/BradyShober/react-native-braintree-dropin-ui

The file that is calling the module is

```
import BraintreeDropIn from 'react-native-braintree-dropin-ui';

const showBraintreeUI = async (token, amount) => {
    BraintreeDropIn.show({
        clientToken: token,
        countryCode: 'US',
        currencyCode: 'USD',
        orderTotal: amount,
        googlePay: true,
        googleMerchantId: 'merchantID',
        applePay: true,
        merchantName: "Name",
        merchantIdentifier: "ID",
        vaultManager: true
    })
    .then(async (result) => {
        console.log(result)
        }
        catch(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        if (error.code === 'USER_CANCELLATION') {
            console.log("User cancelled payment");
        }
        else {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}

export { getBraintreeToken, showBraintreeUI };
```

The expected result is the opening of the Braintree Drop In UI which works on Android but on iOS is throwing an error TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined.

I believe this to be an issue with autolinking, I have been able to get it to work if I right click Libraries in Xcode, then Add files and select the module's .xcodeproject and then add the library in Link Binaries with Libraries. I haven't been able to easily find what I would have to change in the module to not have to do those steps as a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it working thanks to some help I got on the Reactiflux discord server. The issue was due to an issue in the module's Podspec that was causing none of the module's source files to be detected. The s.source_files was set to `s.source_files  = "RNBraintreeDropIn/**/*.{h,m}"` instead of `s.source_files  = "*.{h,m}"`

Comment: Can you please provide more information? Your answer isn't helpful at all. What are other people supposed to do from now on, join Discord servers?

Comment: @MaximZubarev I've added the specific issue and fix